# why d8 not runs from console path?

Tags: v8

When running d8 from the console path, it works fine. But adding this path to .bashrc as export PATH="$HOME/pathtod8/":$PATH causes it to fail.
Failed to open startup resource 'snapshot_blob.bin'.

```
   # Fatal error in , line 0
   # Failed to deserialize the V8 snapshot blob. This can mean that the snapshot blob file is corrupted or missing.
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffe16d4a3e0
==== C stack trace ===============================

    d8(v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()+0x13) [0x56217b2bdf83]
    d8(+0x1d4b46b) [0x56217b2bd46b]
    d8(V8_Fatal(char const*, ...)+0x145) [0x56217b2af9a5]
    d8(v8::Isolate::Initialize(v8::Isolate*, v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&)+0x2da) [0x56217a20c53a]
    d8(v8::Isolate::New(v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&)+0x1d) [0x56217a20c62d]
    d8(v8::Shell::Main(int, char**)+0x51a) [0x56217a1ccbfa]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2718a) [0x7f4f6232f18a]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x85) [0x7f4f6232f245]
    d8(_start+0x2a) [0x56217a1a302a]
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*console path*"?

Comment: I meant that when iI'am exactly in the current directory with d8 it works fine. But not works throw other places.

Answer (score 1):

`d8` needs to find `snapshot_blob.bin` in the current directory (it doesn't check `PATH` for that), or alternatively it needs to be compiled with `v8_use_external_startup_data = false` in `args.gn`.